# What is the meaning of expression "embrace aggressively"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've been reading a book "Java Persistence with Hibernate", 2nd edition and have stumbled upon this phrase: "The Java Persistence and Bean Validation standards embrace annotations aggressively."

To my mind it simply means that they are using annotations extensively. But I'm not sure. Or maybe it means that they so welcome the idea of annotations.

Please, help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They consciously and deliberately use the annotation approach as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

"Eager and wholehearted acceptance of someone or some concept or thought with zero reservations" would be my definition of EMBRACE here.
So, I will go with "To my mind it simply means that they are using annotations extensively."